# How to place external links on button click in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

I have an app designed for a student body, and the thing is I want to have some buttons which will redirect the users to particular social networking pages of that student body (say, Instagram, LinkedIn....) But when I try to copy the link of the pages and paste it in button onclick and try to open it clicking the button, it says link broken or page isn't available.... How to do it properly??

Comment: Can you add your source code. It helps others to identify what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way on button OnClickListener()

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/")));
```

Should work.